# Security ProviderInstaller alternative for devices without Play Services

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

Is there any alternatives for ProviderInstaller from Play Services? I'm having SSL problems with the conection used by Firestore in devices with Android 11 but no Play Services.

`Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket`

Comment: Could you try from a different device, a VM from android studio and from a different network.   If the issue continues even in these tests could you please share the error message.